# How to extract polygon from multipolygon that has most positive point in Shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

I would like to select a polygon within a multipolygon, which has the highest x coordinate of all polygons in the multipolygon. What I was thinking about was the following:

Let's first create the multipolygon:

```
poly1 = Polygon([(20, 20), (200, 20), (200, 180), (20, 180)])
poly2 = Polygon([(40, 20), (220, 20), (220, 180), (40, 180)])
multipoly = MultiPolygon(poly1, poly2)
```

Loop through the polygons in the multipolygons and check the maximum value of the x coordinates:

```
max_list = []

#get highest x coordinate of all polygons in the multipolygon and add that to a list
for item in multipoly:
    x, y = item.exterior.xy
    max_list.append(max(x))

#select the polygon which matches the index of the highest x coordinate of the max_list (list with maximum x coordinates of all polygons)
for idx, item in enumerate(multipoly):
    if idx == max_list.index(max(max_list))):
        break

print(item)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to make this shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.bounds`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.bounds) and [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a lambda function:

```
import shapely
poly1 = shapely.Polygon([(20, 20), (200, 20), (200, 180), (20, 180)])
poly2 = shapely.Polygon([(40, 20), (220, 20), (220, 180), (40, 180)])
multipoly = shapely.MultiPolygon([poly1, poly2])

geoms = [g for g in multipoly.geoms] #List all multipolygon polygons
maxx = max(geoms, key=lambda x: x.bounds[2]) #Bounds is a tuple of (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) so bounds[2] is max X
#maxx.wkt
#'POLYGON ((40 20, 220 20, 220 180, 40 180, 40 20))'
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! I'll accept it as the best answer.

For the people that want don't want the maxx, but minx, maxy or miny, change the line with:
minx:     min(geoms, key=lambda x: x.bounds[0])
miny:     min(geoms, key=lambda x: x.bounds[1])
maxy:     max(geoms, key=lambda x: x.bounds[3])